# Setting read/write permissions on Mongodb folder

Tags: bash, mongodb, file-permissions, chown

I just finished installing MongoDB on OSX and setup a directory structure with `sudo mkdir -p /data/db`.

When I attempt to run `mongod` from my user account it returns an error stating that my user account does not have read/write permission to `/data/db`.

How can I set the proper read/write permissions on my account for `/data/db`?

Answer (score 79):

Ensure that user account running `mongod` has the proper directory permissions. You can check which permissions are set like so:

```
ls -ld /data/db/
```

If they are set properly they should look something like this..

> `drwxr-xr-x  X user  wheel  XXX Date Time /data/db/`

If the permissions are set incorrectly you will likely see an error similar to this when attempting to run `mongod`

> `exception in initAndListen: XXXXX Unable to create/open lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating`

To get the permissions set as they should be you can run the following command

```
sudo chmod 0755 /data/db && sudo chown $USER /data/db
```

Comment: $ sudo chmod 0755 /data/db && **sudo** chown $USER /data/db

Comment: YES! do NOT forget `sudo` on `chown`!

Answer (score 11):

```
sudo chmod 777 /data/db/
```

Should work on Mac.  Before running this cmd, permissions look like

```
drwxr-xr-x  X User  wheel  Date /data/db
```

after running the cmd

```
drwxrwxrwx  X User  wheel  Date /data/db
```

Comment: What does `wheel` mean?  Where you have `User` and `Date` in blue are those supposed to be replaced with something?

Answer (score 6):

This is what worked for me. I am using a Mac, although you could try if you're using windows.

```
sudo chmod 777 /data/db
```

Comment: sudo chmod 0755 /data/db && chown $USER /data/db

Comment: should we not use this for the sake of security?!

Comment: Where you have ` $USER` is this the username for the database or the user account of the computer?  Or do you literally type ` $USER`?  :D Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There are three categories of users: owners, those in the group, and everyone else; `chmod 777 /path/to/file` lets everyone read/write the file, but `chmod 775 /path/to/file` lets only the owner/group read/write the file. Definitely use `chmod 775 /path/to/file` if you're developing a web server.

Some useful reading, especially for reasoning behind why 777, 775, and so on are used rather than other numbers: https://www.maketecheasier.com/file-permissions-what-does-chmod-777-means/

Answer (score 2):

None of these suggestions are correct, there's something else wrong with mongodb-org-3.4.16-1.el7.x86_64. It cannot start with a custom db path.

```
[root@localhost vagrant]# chmod 777 /data/ /data/mongodb
[root@localhost vagrant]# chown mongod:mongod /data/ /data/mongodb
[root@localhost vagrant]# ls -lad /data/mongodb/
drwxrwxrwx. 2 mongod mongod 6 Jul 11 15:24 /data/mongodb/
[root@localhost vagrant]#  systemctl start mongod
Job for mongod.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mongod.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
[root@localhost vagrant]# stat /data/mongodb^C
[root@localhost vagrant]# !tail
tail /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
2018-07-11T15:39:10.786+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 20 Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /data/mongodb, terminating
2018-07-11T15:39:10.786+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2018-07-11T15:39:10.786+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2018-07-11T15:39:10.786+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2018-07-11T15:39:10.786+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
[root@localhost vagrant]# rpm -qa | grep mongo
mongodb-org-tools-3.4.16-1.el7.x86_64
mongodb-org-shell-3.4.16-1.el7.x86_64
mongodb-org-server-3.4.16-1.el7.x86_64
mongodb-org-mongos-3.4.16-1.el7.x86_64
mongodb-org-3.4.16-1.el7.x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run

```
sudo chown group:user /data/db
```

where `group` is a group of your user

Comment: What `does where group is a group of your user` mean? Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

None of the given answers were working for me. I ended up configuring my personal OS user to be the root user, then manually went to the db folder - right clicked to view info - and added myself with read and write permissions.

Answer (score 0):

According to Mongodb University course M103 the permission level will be

```
sudo chmod 600 /path/to/db
```